# Set theory and bijective functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, elementary-set-theory

I was presented with this statement in my discrete mathematics course. So far i can't figure out if it's true or false.

---

Let there be a set $U$. Also, let there be a set $A$ such that $A⊆U$.

For any set $B$, function f is defined as follows:

$f: \mathcal{P}(U) → \mathcal{P}(U)$

$f(B)= A ∩ B$

Prove: $f$ is a bijective function if and only if $A=U$.

Comment: Hint:  What is $f(A^c)$?

Comment: @lulu Sorry but I'm not familiar with that c sign.

Comment: It means the set complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lulu's comment gives you everything you need, but if you like I can furnish an answer based on said comment.  If $f$ is bijective then it must be injective.  However note that by construction $f(A^c) = \emptyset$; since $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ then we must have $A^c = \emptyset \Rightarrow A = U$.  On the other hand if $A = U$ then clearly $f$ is bijective.